# Dynamics 365 OData WebAPI request orderby child property not working?

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, webapi

I want to order the returned list based on a property from the child but I'm getting this error

{"error":{"code":"0x0","message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}}

This request using the OOTB opportunity and account table gives me the error

https://xxx.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/opportunities?$expand=parentaccountid&$top=5&$orderby=parentaccountid/name

I want to get a list of opportunities sorted by the associated account's name. Is this possible to do? Did I not have the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

At least to my knowledge you cannot sort on related properties, the `orderby` clause only works with the properties of the main table you are fetching.

You can use it inside the `expand` clause, something like `$expand=parentaccountid($orderby=name)`, but the order in this case is applied only to the expanded records (so it's useful more in a 1:N relationship) and not to the main records.

Comment: If it's not supported, how would I go about getting the result returned the way I wanted?

Comment: if I remember correctly I saw your question in another dynamics forum. There a user suggested to copy the value to the main table, so you can create a workflow or a plugin to copy the parent account name (every time the parent account changes) to a custom field inside opportunity and sort by this custom field